# What is a more efficient way to do this?

Tags: python

The goal of this code is that the user will enter a string with three "wildcard" symbols in any order. I have assigned a meaning to in my program (? is any letter or number, # is any number, and & is any letter). I then want a list of every combination of the appropriate letters and/or numbers, however it must stay in the same order as the original wildcards. And ultimately I will substitute all those new combinations back into the original string.

```
wildcards = ['?', '#', '&'] #user has entered wildcards in this order
n = len(wildcards)
list = itertools.product('abc123',repeat=n) #creates a cartesian product of every combination of letters and numbers (only using abc123 to be more manageable for now. 
print(list)
for x in list: #going to iterate through the list
    iter = 0
    while iter < n: #iterating through an individual object in the list
        if wildcards[iter] == '#': #if that index should be a number but isn't, we delete that object from the list
            if x[iter] != string.digits:
                del list[x]
        elif wildcards[iter] == '&': #if it should be a letter and isn't we delete the object
            if x[iter] != string.ascii_lowercase:
                del list[x]
        iter = iter+1
print(list) #print the new list
```

I feel like this should work but there must be a much more efficient way to do it. I'm also encountering this error. TypeError: 'itertools.product' object does not support item deletion, so I can't remove the incorrect list items. Is that because it is a tuple and I can't modify tuple elements?

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid re-defining Python's built-in functions and datatypes such as `iter` and `list`

Comment: Are you sure  `if x[iter] != string.digits` is doing what you think?

Comment: @jDo Thanks I will make sure to rename them.

Comment: @padraic-Cunningham, I'm trying to check if the string located at that index in object x is not a digit, then we will do something, did I miss something there? Thanks

Comment: `if x[iter] != string.digits` is checking `if x[iter]` is equal to "0123456789", perhaps you meant `if not x[iter].isdigit()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
import string

user_string = '???'
iterables = []
for c in user_string:
    if c == '?':
        iterables.append(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)
    elif c == '&':
        iterables.append(string.ascii_lowercase)
    elif c == '#':
        iterables.append(string.digits)

for item in itertools.product(*iterables):
    print(''.join(item))
```

You can also make this work in case `user_string` contains characters other than the wildcards:

```
import itertools
import string

user_string = 'aaa???'
iterables = []
for c in user_string:
    if c == '?':
        iterables.append(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)
    elif c == '&':
        iterables.append(string.ascii_lowercase)
    elif c == '#':
        iterables.append(string.digits)
    else:
        iterables.append([c])

for item in itertools.product(*iterables):
    print(''.join(item))
```

Comment: Wow I think that is exactly what I was looking for... thank you. Can you walk me through a couple parts because I don't understand exactly how it worked. What does the * do in product(*iterables). Also, I thought that the cartesian product would have every possibility, so that if the user_string were '&&#', you would still still get results starting with a digit (which is not what I would want), but that does not seem to be what happened!